# How is the method called in static class

Tags: c#, static

My code is as follows

```
   class MyStaticClass
   {

     static MyStaticClass{};

    public static readonly MyStaticClass Instance = CreateMe();
    public static int GetSomeValue = GetValue();

    private static int GetValue()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    private static MyStaticClass CreateMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This method was called");
        return new MyStaticClass();
    }

}
```

public class Program
    {

```
    public static void Main()
    {

         int val=MyStaticClass.GetSomeValue;

    }
 }
```

**O/p:**

`This method was called`

When I call `val` why does the debugger accesses `CreateMe` method ? Is it that any static method I access it will access all the static methods in the class ?

Comment: The title of question needs modification as there is not static class in the code under question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a static initializer for a static field. As part of program startup, all static fields are evaluated.

**Edit:** small clarification here:

The static fields in a particular class are evaluated in declaration order, but there in no particular order for which class has it's static fields initialized first.
Now, if you had a static property, that would be different.

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: `All static fields are evaluated in no particular order`  +1

Comment: The order is not random. First sentence in your link says it is in textual order. So `Instance` first, then `GetSomeValue` and static constructor after that.

Answer (score 4):

The method `CreateMe()` is called because you are calling in when you create object `Instance`  in the following statement.

```
 public static readonly MyStaticClass Instance = CreateMe();
```

This is static object in your class and is created as you access the class which you did by `MyStaticClass.GetSomeValue`.

[Dubugging the code](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) will give you clear view of the order of the statements get executed. You can go through this detailed article on MSDN regarding debugging [Debugger Roadmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k0k771bt(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: you mean to say when I type `MyStaticClass.GetSomeValue` The keyword `MyStaticClass` will invoke instance ?

Comment: Not the key word but accessing the class MyStaticClass. It could be due to accessing the static property or method etc.

Comment: ok so any method I access other than 'instance' it will by default initialize all the static methods ?

Comment: The static method are not implicitly called, you have called explicitly when you created object having name Instance. All the static data members are initialized/instantiated when you access the any member through class.

Answer (score 0):

Both fields have been initialized using the static methods. So, in that case, all the static methods will be evaluated.